# Can't call a function in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Ok so I am sure that the error is something really dumb, but for some reason I can't get it, so I would greatly appreciate some help :)

```
 local function Selector()
  x = math.random(1,2)
  if x == 1 then
    Veshtica

  end
end
```

"Veshtica" is the function that I want to call.
 Error message - ""=" expected near end"

Comment: `ocal`, is this a typo just here? Where are the braces?  Veshtica()?

Comment: More exactly, `Veshtica` is an expression that evaluates to a reference to a function value that you want to call. The error means you don't have a statement where one is expected. A function call can be either an expression or a statement, but you don't have a function call, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When [calling a function in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html) without parameters you need to include the parenthesis.

> If the function call has no arguments, we must write an empty list () to indicate the call.

Thereby you need to do `Veshtica()` and can't do just `Veshtica`.

*If the function call has parameters then you can do `print("Hello World!")` but also simply `print "Hello World!"`.*

*Note that:*

> There is a special case to this rule: If the function has one single argument and this argument is either a literal string or a table constructor, then the parentheses are optional.

In other words, you can do `print "Hello World!"` but you can't do `math.cos 10`.

Comment: Only if you pass one string or table literal can you call a function without parenthesis.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo look at the link I added, it clearly says *"If the function call has no arguments, we must write an empty list () to indicate the call."*

Comment: Yes. Zero arguments is not one literal string/table.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo true, but you can easily use numbers and booleans as well.

Comment: No, it's only string and table literals.